# Can't able to make responsive background image

Tags: responsive-design

My background body is image and the container is also the image but container image is responsive while background is not. I tried every method but still no luck. please help, here is my code:

```
body{
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/T05z1d7.jpg); (This image should be responsive)
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 }
.container{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.paper{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

<div class="container"> (This image is already responsive)
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/94fCwZx.jpg" class="paper">
</div>
```

Comment: There's only one image in your code. Which one is responsive? Which one is supposed to be responsive?

Comment: Sorry, i am noob here. body{background:url()} image: imgur should be responsive. That one is the background image. I have updated the second image too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
body{
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/T05z1d7.jpg);
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

with this

```
body{
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/T05z1d7.jpg);
background-size: 100%;
}
```